# how to Display blob image stored in MYSQL to image in windows 8.1 apps

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, blob

I saved an image into mysql as Blob normally from visual studio windows 8.1 project but I need to retrieve this image and put it into Image tool.

This code below to insert image into Mysql:

```
public static void insertImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker imagePicker = new FileOpenPicker
    {
        ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
        FileTypeFilter = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp" }
    };

    StorageFile imageFile = await imagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    string a = imageFile.Name;

    string FileName = a;

    var inputStream = await imageFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
    var readStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    var buffer = new byte[readStream.Length];
    await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    size = buffer.Length;

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
           "server=localhost;database=familytree;uid=root;"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE node SET avatar = '" + 
                     buffer + "' WHERE     email = '" + email + "'", connection);
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to store the picture :

private static async Task FileToByteArray(Uri sourceUri)
{

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(sourceUri);
using (var inputStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    var readStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    var buffer = new byte[readStream.Length];
    await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return buffer;
}
```

}

and to retrieve it:

private static async Task ConvertToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
        {

```
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            var dw = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            dw.WriteBytes(imageBytes);
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            image.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
        }
        return image;
    }
```